# Java program for splitting strings with line breaks and stops with no entry not working?

Tags: java

This is the problem I'm trying to solve:

[image: screenshot]

My code is the following:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LineByLine {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String sentence = String.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            String[] pieces = sentence.split(" ");

            for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(pieces[i]);
            }
            if (sentence.equals("")) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code is showing as wrong and I'm unsure why. Any explanations?

Answer (score 3):

You should arrange your code like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while (true) { 
        String sentence = String.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
        String[] pieces = sentence.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(pieces[i]);
        } 
        if (sentence.equals("")) {
            break;
        }
   }
   scanner.close();
}
```

Also you could use hasNext method instead of `while(true)` part:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    while (scanner.hasNext()) { 
        String sentence = scanner.nextLine();
        String[] pieces = sentence.split(" ");

        for (int i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(pieces[i]);
        } 
   }
   scanner.close();
}
```

Comment: I also think that `String sentence = String.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());` can be replaced with `String sentence = scanner.nextLine();`

Comment: Yeap, I didn't notice that part :) I will update the answer Vladislav, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to place:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
```

outside of the `while` loop.

**The reason:**

You only need to create a single `Scanner` object. This has to be done before you enter the loop since the instantiation will consume the standard input - this means that after the first iteration of the loop, there will be no standard input left to instantiate the object once again.

*You can also think about it more mechanically than that:*

If you had a loop that was meant to iterate through numbers, you wouldn't want to be resetting your loop counter each time, right? Its quite a similar thing in this case.

Comment: Wow. Thank you! Can you explain why the scanner needs to be outside the while loop?

Comment: Sure. You only need to create a single `Scanner` object. This has to be done before you enter the loop since the instantiation will consume the standard input - this means that after the first iteration of the loop, there will be no standard input left to instantiate the object once again.

You can also think about it more mechanically than that:

If you had a loop that was meant to iterate through numbers, you wouldn't want to be resetting your loop counter each time, right? Its quite a similar thing in this case.

Comment: Amazing. Makes much more sense. Thank you so much!

Comment: Your welcome. Also take a look at @stuck's suggestions, especially the layout & indentation which helps to increase readability and reduce bugs.

Comment: Instead of String sentence = String.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());  just write  String sentence = scanner.nextLine(); ... the nextLine() method already returns a type String.